# mysql inner join with count query

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join

I have the following query to pull properties. Properties have multiple units. I have no idea how to pull properties with at least 1 unit though. Units are connected to the properties by having the same "team". The "team" is a varchar(ex. "jkdgsl"). Any suggestions?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Properties.id, Properties.title, Properties.team
FROM Properties
INNER JOIN Units ON Units.team = Properties.team 
AND Units.rates != '0' 
AND Properties.deleted =  '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND Properties.zip_code
IN (
'77808',  '77845'
)
AND Properties.public =  '1'
ORDER BY FIELD( Properties.zip_code,  '77808',  '77845' ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: It seems to me that your query already works and pulls the properties you need because an `INNER JOIN` between `properties` and `units` will essentially exclude all properties which don't have a corresponding row in `units`, thus pulling properties with at least 1 unit. If you wanted to pull only properties with 2 or more units however, that's a different story, where you'll need `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` perhaps within a subselect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are already doing that (i.e. select properties that have at least one unit) by the nature of an inner join.

Comment: this is an answer or comment?

Comment: @FranciscoSpaeth: Man, you are all crazy with this observation. It's obviously an answer since it appears in the answer section. If you're asking me whether it SHOULD be a comment or an answer, my logic tells me it should be an answer because it answers his question

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Razvan 
If you also want the count of units, use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Properties.id, Properties.title, Properties.team, COUNT(Units.<em>someOTHERcolumn</em>)
FROM Properties
INNER JOIN Units ON Units.team = Properties.team 
AND Units.rates != '0' 
AND Properties.deleted =  '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND Properties.zip_code
IN (
'77808',  '77845'
)
AND Properties.public =  '1'
GROUP BY Properties.id ORDER BY FIELD( Properties.zip_code,  '77808',  '77845' ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one or more, you could use `COALESCE`.

```
WHERE COALESCE( Properties.id, Properties.title, Properties.team ) IS NOT NULL
```